# Getting an error message on while installing any packages in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mariadb, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-18.04

While trying to install any packages/apt in my ubuntu terminal after installing showing some error messages.

for example, I'm trying to install zip

```
sudo apt-get install zip
```

after execution above command, I'll get this kind of error message.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
zip is already the newest version (3.0-11build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up phpmyadmin (4:4.6.6-5) ...
dbconfig-common: writing config to /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf
dbconfig-common: flushing administrative password
dpkg: error processing package phpmyadmin (--configure):
 installed phpmyadmin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 phpmyadmin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this issues in my every time showing error message phpmyadmin thing

Comment: Hello and welcome to Server Fault! While `zip` looks like is already installed (`zip is already the newest version (3.0-11build1).`), you can try to get rid of the `phpmyadmin` error with 'sudo apt-get -f install` and/or 'apt-get install --reinstall phpmyadmin`.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply, I'm asking `Setting up phpmyadmin (4:4.6.6-5) ...` ( after line 9) it is showing an error message for any package install, not able to fix that issue I'm looking for a solution for that

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get -f install` and `sudo apt-get install --reinstall phpmyadmin`?

Comment: yes but still that error is there